# How to find whether a file is an executable in node.js

Tags: node.js, process

I am looking for a platform independent (win, mac, linux) way of finding whether a file is executable or not. Following doesn't work for me (not even on linux) -

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var proc = spawn("whatever file");
proc.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  if (/^execvp\(\)/.test(data)) {
    console.log('Failed to start child process.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the [mime-magic](https://npmjs.org/package/mime-magic) nodejs module to find out about the mime types of the files.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise strongly against executing a file as a way to test whether it's executable. If you don't know what a file is, don't just run it! This is a security and general damage nightmare. This is analogous to testing whether a vial of clear liquid is poison by drinking it.

## Step 1: read it's metadata via `stat`

On posix (linux, mac, bsd), use `fs.stat` then examine the `mode` field to check for the various permutations executable.

## Step 2: read the beginning of the file data and guess the type

You can run the [file utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) on it, which will use a database of magic numbers and other heuristics to guess the file type.

## Windows

In terms of platform independent, AFAIK this functionality just isn't similar enough on Windows for there to be a reliable Windows equivalent of the above posix-oriented techniques. Windows filesystems and filetypes are different, so I think if you want this to really work, you'll need a separate implementation to handle windows properly (and someone other than me to suggest how to implement it on windows).